# How to properly copy char array to char array?

Tags: c, arrays, copy

I am quite a newbie on `C` and am trying to get a C routine working.

```
const char *filenames[entry_count];
for (i = 0; i < entry_count; i++) {
    char filename_inzip[256];
    unz_file_info file_info;
    err = unzGetCurrentFileInfo(uf, &file_info, filename_inzip,
            sizeof(filename_inzip), NULL, 0, NULL, 0); 

    //This doesn't work. My array gets filled with the last entry over and over.
    filenames[i] = filename_inzip; //Option 1

    //Here I get SIGSEV errors, or gibberish in output when debugging values
    strcpy(filenames[i], filename_inzip); //Option 2
}
```

I guess the first assignment doesn't work because it just points to the same temporary memory address of the `char[256]` in the loop.

The second option doesn't work I think because I haven't use `malloc` or similar.

How would I get a properly filled array?

Comment: `filenames[i]` is not a `char` array. It's a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that you need to allocate memory in the second option.

```
filenames[i] = strdup(filename_inzip);
```

is the easiest way of doing this.

`strdup` is a Posix function rather than standard C.  If it isn't available for you

```
filenames[i] = malloc(strlen(filename_inzip)+1);
if (filenames[i] != NULL) {
    strcpy(filenames[i], filename_inzip);
}
```

does an equivalent job

Note that you'll also have to call `free` for each array element you allocate later in your program.

Comment: Ok, will I need to use a loop and then call free on each?

Comment: Yes.  Take care not to call `free` on any element whose value is unassigned however.  Behaviour of `free(NULL)` is well defined so setting all elements to `NULL` at the start of your code would allow you to just loop through indexes [0..entry_count] later on without worrying about how many elements were actually allocated.

Comment: I guess there's not a way to `free` the complete array with a single call and not in a loop?

Comment: No.  As a general rule, every call to `malloc` must have exactly one later matching call to `free`.  If you call `malloc` in a loop you should therefore expect to later call `free` in a loop also.